# Beagle dando crash na função getBeagleCacheFromDisk com cache desabiltiado

Tags: android, mobile, app

Estou usando o Beagle 1.4 (usebeagle.io) em um aplicativo Android parcialmente server driven. Estou com o cache desabilitado no BeagleConfig, mas quando chego na tela com a UI Beagle, o app dá um crash. Não sei se é possível habilitar o cache de outra forma, e não tenho como perguntar para todos os desenvolvedores do app. Se for possível habilitar de outras formas, preciso saber de todas para desativá-las.

```
@BeagleComponent
class AppBeagleConfig : BeagleConfig {
    override val isLoggingEnabled: Boolean = ServerDrivenConfig.data.isDebug
    override val baseUrl: String = ServerDrivenConfig.data.baseUrl
    override val environment: Environment = ServerDrivenConfig.data.environment
    override val cache: Cache = Cache(
        enabled = false,
        maxAge = 300
    )
}
```

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
    Process: com.example, PID: 0000
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at br.com.zup.beagle.android.cache.CacheManager.getBeagleCacheFromDisk(CacheManager.kt:89)
        at br.com.zup.beagle.android.cache.CacheManager.restoreCacheFromDisk(CacheManager.kt:69)
        at br.com.zup.beagle.android.cache.CacheManager.restoreBeagleCacheForUrl(CacheManager.kt:60)
        at br.com.zup.beagle.android.data.ComponentRequester.fetchComponent(ComponentRequester.kt:36)
        at br.com.zup.beagle.android.view.viewmodel.BeagleViewModel$FetchComponentLiveData$fetchComponents$1.invokeSuspend(BeagleViewModel.kt:84)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:56)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:738)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
```

Comment: duvida respondida aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/480901/problema-no-cache-do-beagle-1-4/480902#480902