# Problema no cache do Beagle 1.4

Tags: android, mobile, app

Estou usando o Beagle 1.4 (usebeagle.io) em um aplicativo Android parcialmente server driven. Estou com o cache desabilitado no BeagleConfig, mas quando chego na tela com a UI Beagle, o app dá um crash. Não sei se é possível habilitar o cache de outra forma, e não tenho como perguntar para todos os desenvolvedores do app. Se for possível habilitar de outras formas, preciso saber de todas para desativá-las.

```
@BeagleComponent
class AppBeagleConfig : BeagleConfig {
    override val isLoggingEnabled: Boolean = ServerDrivenConfig.data.isDebug
    override val baseUrl: String = ServerDrivenConfig.data.baseUrl
    override val environment: Environment = ServerDrivenConfig.data.environment
    override val cache: Cache = Cache(
        enabled = false,
        maxAge = 300
    )
}
```

```
at br.com.zup.beagle.android.cache.CacheManager.getBeagleCacheFromDisk(CacheManager.kt:89)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem uma PR aberta: https://github.com/ZupIT/beagle/pull/1114 e isso vai ser resolvido na versão 1.4.1